# Simplifying Jquery Code

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I'm fairly new to jQuery and have been experimenting with the following.

```
var datastartscale = $(this).attr('data-start-scale');

$(this).css({'transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
             '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
             '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
             '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')'});
```

I've been trying to put the css data into a variable without success.
I need to call this variable multiple times which is why storing all this data in a variable would be most ideal.

```
var properties = "'transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')','-ms-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')','-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')','-moz-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')'";
```

and then I would write:

```
 $(this).css({properties});
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why not: `var properties = {'transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')','-ms-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')','-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')','-moz-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')'};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the properties as an object :

```
var properties = {'transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
                  '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
                  '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
                  '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')'
                 }
$(this).css(properties);
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, I also like your formatting, much easier to follow than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
var properties = {'transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
         '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
         '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
         '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')'}
```

and

```
$(this).css(properties);
```

Comment: The curly brackets around `properties` in the `.css()` call should not be there.

Comment: You are correct, this works perfectly once I removed the curly brackets around $(this).css({properties}); to $(this).css(properties);

Answer (score 0):

The variable should contain an object, just like the argument to the function, not a string:

```
var properties = {'transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
                  '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
                  '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')',
                  '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + datastartscale + ')'};
```